# Delay to run code (prototype)

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, delay

I am modifing a Magento template, and want to have 1-2s delay to run 2 line:
            popup.style.display = 'none';
            $(menuId).removeClassName('active');

I don't understand javascript at all, how can I do this, thanks

```
function wppHideMenuPopup(element, event, popupId, menuId)
{
    element = $(element.id); var popup = $(popupId); if (!popup) return;
    var current_mouse_target = null;
    if (event.toElement)
    {
        current_mouse_target = event.toElement;
    }
    else if (event.relatedTarget)
    {
        current_mouse_target = event.relatedTarget;
    }
    if (!wppIsChildOf(element, current_mouse_target) && element != current_mouse_target)
    {
        if (!wppIsChildOf(popup, current_mouse_target) && popup != current_mouse_target)
        {
            popup.style.display = 'none';
            $(menuId).removeClassName('active');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use window.setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);

Usage > window.setInterval("hidethething()",2000);

Just place that (and replace with the correct function) wherever you want to start counting the 2 secs.

Thanks,
@leo

Comment: Thanks leo, is this correct?                 window.setinterval(function(){popup.style.display = 'none';$(menuId).removeClassName('actiwe');},2000);

Comment: setInverval is great, but it's tricky. You need to put the function name inside quotes, so it is basically a string, and you will not be able to put variables. What I ussually do is to create another function  with no parameters and from there do the magic.

Comment: Thanks leo, I finally use setTimeout and get great result, setTimeout(function(){popup.style.display = 'none'; $(menuId).removeClassName('actiwe');},10);